# Strip line comments and not url

Tags: java

Suppose we want to preprocess JSON strings to strip out C style line comments. An example might look

like this:

```
// this is a comment

{ // another comment

 true, "foo", // 3rd comment

 "http://www.abc.com" // comment after URL

}
```

Write a function to strip line comments.

I have tried by using regex:

```
replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|(?://.*)","")
```

This removes url and i get output as:

```
  { 
 true,foo , 
http:
}
```

I want the url i.e. i want my output to be as 
  { 
 true,foo , 
http://www.abc.com
}

thanks for the help

Comment: You could count the number of opening/closing quotation marks to see whether you are currently inside a string.

Comment: Counting quotation marks will fail if you have `\"` somewhere inside the string.  But then you'd also have to count backslashes, because `\\"` would _not_ be a quoted quote mark.  I think it's possible to write a complicated regex that handles all of this, but at this point you're probably best off using a JSON parser, or writing a simple one yourself.  Regexes just can't handle everything, and complicated regexes are the leading cause of migraines in programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the last clause of your regexp `(?://.*)` you are matching on `//`, but what you want to do is match on `//` but NOT on `://`.

Once solution would be to replace your rule with a couple like this:

a) match `//` when there is a non `:` character in front of it: `[^:]//.*`

b) match `//` if it is at the beginning of a line: `^//.*`

Try this:

```
    String input = "// this is a comment\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "{ // another comment\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            " true, \"foo\", // 3rd comment\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            " \"http://www.abc.com\" // comment after URL\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "}";

    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|[^:]//.*|^//.*",""));
```

Comment: May I suggest you expand your answer by adding an explanation of the changes made to the regexp, and why they work?